# Overriding default popup anchor in Leaflet GeoJSON polygon?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, popup

By default popups open wherever you click within the boundaries of polygons in Leaflet geojson layers. Here's an example:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9LLyd6f/32/)

I would like to anchor the popup either:

so it opens in a specific place on the map (setLatLong)

or

at a specific coordinate relative to where the cursor clicks on the polygon. (anchorPopup)

I know from docs that this can be achieved using anchorPopup or openPopup: if this be the case where does one add this to the code?

My code is similar to the jsfiddle:

```
var outcroppings = L.geoJson(outcroppings,{

 style: function(feature, layer){
    return { 
        color: "black",
        fillColor: "orange", 
        fillOpacity: 6, 
        weight: 2,

    };
},

   onEachFeature: function (feature, layer){
    layer.bindPopup(

                    "<img src='" + feature.properties.image + "'style=  width:100px  >"+
                    "</p>area: "+feature.properties.Shape_Area
                   );      
}

 }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the setLatLng() method chained onto the popup.  If you enter the coordinates where you want the popup to appear, it should stay in that location.

So, I think it should look like this:

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer){
layer.bindPopup(

                "<img src='" + feature.properties.image + "'style=  
width:100px  >"+
                "</p>area: "+feature.properties.Shape_Area
               );      
}

  }).setLatLng(LatLng).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Nope, that made the feature vanish.. :(

Comment: Do you get a message in the console, or does it just disappear?

Comment: I get a mesasage:  TypeError: L.geoJson(...).setLatLng is not a function.

Comment: When I follow the error message it highlights ' var outcroppings= L.geojson(outcroppings,  '

Comment: You cannot call `setLatLng()` on the layer, but this is what you are  trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate the popup with a layer source (see the Creation section of the [popup documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#popup)) and then set its coordinates:

```
L.popup(popupOptions,layer).setContent(content).setLatLng(lat_lng)
```